# Hot to refer to an entire array

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

How do i refer to an entire array when comparing 2 components.

```
    var array:[String] = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
    if textfield.text == array[]{

println("color good")
}
```

how do i check if the textfield is = any of the array components, not just a specific one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if contains(array, textfield.text) {
     ...
```